# NSX Manager - Cannot access APIs with the 'admin' user and password which was set during installation

Tags: vmware

I had installed NSX Manager using the OVF image provided by VMware. During installation I had to provide 2 passwords, one for the CLI and another one for privileged mode. After installation, I am able to login to NSX manager via web client, but when I try to access its APIs, it responds with 403.

I was trying to access the basic authentication GET API.

`curl -sik -u 'username' -H ‘Content-Type: application/xml’ -X GET https://hostname/2.0/services/auth/basic`

`Full authentication is required to access this resource
The server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.`

What could be the issue?

Comment: Is this NSX-V or NSX-T?

Comment: It is NSX-V. I made a silly mistake by missing some part of the API path. It is working now.